# Aligning images like google image search does

Tags: php, html, css

Google shows its images like this:
[image: align1]

But then when I try to do it, I get this:

[image: align]

It seems this will need something more than just float:left, but what? The images will be of unknown height and width. But I put in a max-height and max-width check so it doesn't get too crazy.

Note: rowtable is just an array that holds the picture name (id). I cut some stuff out to clean the code.

```
function imageResize($image) {

$maxWidth  = 500;
$maxHeight = 395;

$size = getimagesize($image);
if ($size) {
    $imageWidth  = $size[0];
    $imageHeight = $size[1];
    $wRatio = $imageWidth / $maxWidth;
    $hRatio = $imageHeight / $maxHeight;
    $maxRatio = max($wRatio, $hRatio);
    if ($maxRatio > 1) {
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth / $maxRatio;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight / $maxRatio;
    } else {
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight;
    }
    //echo 'width="'.$outputWidth.'" height="'.$outputHeight.'"';
return 'width="'.$outputWidth.'" height="'.$outputHeight.'"';
}

}
        $image = "images/screenshots/$rowtable[id].png";
        ?>
        <div style="float:left; padding:5px;"><img src="<?php echo "images/screenshots/$rowtable[id].png"; ?>" <?php echo imageResize($image); ?>></div>
```

UPDATE:

After watcher's comment, it works. But how can I get this?

[image: align3]

So have a wide picture center vertically, rather than sticking to the top.

Comment: make the containing div's height the max-height you want; give the padding to the img

Comment: @PetrMarek how can I know when to close off a containing div and start a new one? As the user changes the browser window size, more (or less) pictures will be shown per line.

Comment: FYI, always try reverse-engineering. Use, Chrome's developer tool (f12) or Firefox's.
In Chrome, choose the image, right click and select inspect element. You will see CSS options on the right, uncheck the marks and see what's the purpose of it. That way you can learn way better and faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's Image Search puts the images into an ordered list, with each list element having the following styles:

```
.rg_li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 12px 12px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, would you happen to know how to center wide pictures vertically as well? I updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 1):

may that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/EAGQH/28/

css:

```
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

img{vertical-align:middle}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at how Google does it in Firebug (or any equivalent tool).  I just did, and apparently they wrap each image in a div (actually, a <li>) with height set to the height of the image and vertical padding set to make up the difference.  For example, here's one of them from a search I just ran:

```
<li class="rg_li" style="width: 140px; height: 89px; padding: 11px 0pt;">
```

(See [watcher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794077/aligning-images-like-google-image-search-does/7794142#7794142) for the styles applied to the class `rg_li`.)  Apparently, they also adjust the height of each line dynamically to match the height of the tallest image on it, so if I resize the window, the padding values get recomputed.

But anyway, if you just want a bunch of images vertically centered, **you don't need any of this trickery**.  Just wrap all the images together in a <p> or <div> and style them with `vertical-align: middle`.

```
<p style="text-align: justify">
  <img style="vertical-align: middle" src="..." />
  <img style="vertical-align: middle" src="..." />
  ...
</p>
```

You can even do this without CSS if you want, by using the old HTML `align` attribute, like this:

```
<p align="justify">
  <img align="middle" src="..." />
  <img align="middle" src="..." />
  ...
</p>
```